# How to cache GraphQL requests?

Tags: magento2, graphql, pwa-studio

My Magento 2.4 isn't caching requests I use many times, like **storeConfig** via PWA Studio.

My request header:

```
x-cache-hits: 0
```

How could I cache this kind of request to optimize the speed of my page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **storeConfig** cache will be released in the lasted version of Magento 2.4.7, so you will be able to update it to have it.

About other requests, you need to create a Resolver, then specified it in your GraphQL schema.

```
@doc(description: "The store config query") @cache(cacheIdentity: "Magento\\StoreGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\Store\\Identity")
```

You can see an example of it in the [Magento 2 Core storeConfig cache implementation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/35392/files).

Don't forget to make sure you configured the [Caching with Varnish](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/usage/caching/#caching-with-varnish) or [Caching with Fastly](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/usage/caching/#caching-with-fastly) steps too.

Comment: Till now Magento 2.4.7 is not released yet. I think you have to correct the magento version in your answer

Comment: It will be included in the 2.4.7, thank you, I updated the comment in my answer.